# stb_truetype.h and SDL2 change font color

Tags: c, sdl-2, truetype

I am using stb_truetype.h and SDL2 to render text. Is there an easy way to change the font color? Here is what I have (text is a char*):

```
while (*text) {
    if (*text >= 32 && *text < 128) {
      stbtt_aligned_quad q;
      stbtt_GetBakedQuad(font->cdata, 512, 512, *text - 32, &x, &y, &q, 1);
      SDL_Rect src_rect = {.x = (int)512 * q.s0 - 1,
                           .y = (int)512 * (q.t0) - 1,
                           .w = (int)512 * (q.s1 - q.s0) + 1,
                           .h = (int)512 * (q.t1 - q.t0) + 1};
      SDL_Rect dst_rect = {
          .x = q.x0, .y = q.y0, .w = q.x1 - q.x0, .h = q.y1 - q.y0};


      // Has no effect because I am just grabbing a rect from the font data.
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
      // Always renders the font white.
      SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, font->texture, &src_rect, &dst_rect);
    }
    ++text;
}
```

I would like to be able to render the font in different colors. Right now the font is always white.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureColorMod?

Comment: Thanks for the help, that works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this, using SDL_SetTextureColorMod : (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureColorMod)

```
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(font->texture, 255, 0, 0);
```

will turn the font red for example.

My original code using this:

```
while (*text) {
    if (*text >= 32 && *text < 128) {
      stbtt_aligned_quad q;
      stbtt_GetBakedQuad(font->cdata, 512, 512, *text - 32, &x, &y, &q, 1);
      SDL_Rect src_rect = {.x = (int)512 * q.s0 - 1,
                           .y = (int)512 * (q.t0) - 1,
                           .w = (int)512 * (q.s1 - q.s0) + 1,
                           .h = (int)512 * (q.t1 - q.t0) + 1};
      SDL_Rect dst_rect = {
          .x = q.x0, .y = q.y0, .w = q.x1 - q.x0, .h = q.y1 - q.y0};

      // set the font texture to display red.
      SDL_SetTextureColorMod(font->texture, 255, 0, 0);
      SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, font->texture, &src_rect, &dst_rect);
    }
    ++text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Edited the answer.